# How to build Jenkins pipeline input parameters dynamically with Groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins pipeline, it is possible to request input data using

```
def returnValue = input message: 'Need some input', 
   parameters: [string(defaultValue: 'adefval', description: 'a', name: 'aaa'),
                string(defaultValue: 'bdefval', description: 'b', name: 'bbb')]
```

To build such a list dynamically, I tried something like

```
def list = ["foo","bar"]
def inputRequest = list.collect  { string(defaultValue: "def", description: 'description', name: it)  }

def returnValue = input message: 'Need some input', parameters: [inputRequest]
```

This does not work:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.InputStep.setParameters() expects class hudson.model.ParameterDefinition but received class java.util.ArrayList

Probably, Groovy can figure out dynamically in the first case which object is required, but in the second case it does not work anymore, as collect returns an ArrayList?

How to create such a list correctly?

<sub>edit: maybe this question not very useful for itself, but may still serve as a code sample...</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Ok it was quite a simple fix, as the collect already returns an `ArrayList`, it should not be wrapped into another list when setting the parameters...

```
def returnValue = input message: 'Need some input', parameters: inputRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while, but it's not as complicated as I thought.

At its simplest, you can define an empty array and fill it with parameter types.
I'm honestly not clear on what the object type is, but it works.

```
ArrayList pa = []

if(<some conditional>) {
    pa += choice (name: 'source_feed',       choices: ['Development', 'Production'])
    pa += string (name: 'deployVersion',     defaultValue: 'Latest',    description: 'version')
    pa += extendedChoice (name: 'environments',      value: 'one,two,three',  description: 'envs', type: 'PT_CHECKBOX')
    pa += booleanParam   (name: 'dryRunMode',        defaultValue: false,       description: 'dry')
    pa += booleanParam   (name: 'skipPreChecks',     defaultValue: false,       description: 'skip')
}

else if (<some other conditional>) {
    pa += string (name: 'CommandServiceVersion', defaultValue: '', description: 'commandservice')
}

def result = input message: "Enter Parameters",
      ok: 'ok go!',
      parameters: pa

echo result.toString()
```

As long as you can pass the `Array[]` around, it works. I ended up creating the `array[]` outside the pipeline, as a global, so it can be passed around throughout the run; as opposed to an env var, which can only be a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the the following code. It will generate the choices A,B,C for you. This can be found by using the Pipeline syntax option in Jenkins. I use it because it saves time and less typos.

```
def createInputParameters(){
properties([[$class: 'RebuildSettings', autoRebuild: false, rebuildDisabled: 
false],parameters([choice(choices: ['A', 'B', 'C'], description: '', name: 
'Test')]),
[$class: 'ThrottleJobProperty', categories: [],
limitOneJobWithMatchingParams: false,
maxConcurrentPerNode: 0, maxConcurrentTotal: 0,
 paramsToUseForLimit: '',
  throttleEnabled: false,
   throttleOption: 'project']])
```

}

Comment: This isn't the answer the OP is looking for. You're just declaring the param as a static list. (And a lot of other noise irrelevant to the question.) What the OP - and myself, incidentally - are looking for is a way to _dynamically_ populate the parameters list with various options.