# How to exit from the Jenkins pipeline if a stage sets build fail/unstable status?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a declarative Jenkins pipeline with `stage1`, `stage2`, `stage3` and so on. I want to stop `stage2` from running if `stage1` sets the build unstable/fail.

I know I can stop the steps in `stage1` from running using `return` when the build is not success but couldn't find a way where I can just exit the pipeline without running the stages below `stage1`

Here is what I have:

```
    stage('stage1') {
            steps {
                script{
                    //somesteps
                    if ("${stdout}" == "1"){
                    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                    return
                    } //if
                    //somesteps
            } //script
        } //steps
    } //stage

    // run only when stage1 is success
    stage('stage2'){
        when {
            expression { 
             params.name ==~ /x|y/
            }
        }
        steps {
            script{
                    //stage2 steps
            }
        }
    }
```

If `params.name ==~ /z/` stage 3 will be executed skippping stage2

Note: I cannot include the steps in stage2/3/.. in stage1. It should be that way. Based on the build paramters stage2/3/4... will be called after stage1

Comment: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667600/abort-current-build-from-pipeline-in-jenkins

Answer (score 46):

The easiest way to skip remaining pipeline stages is to set up a variable which will control if following stages should be skipped or not. Something like this:

```
def skipRemainingStages = false

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            steps {
                script {
                    skipRemainingStages = true

                    println "skipRemainingStages = ${skipRemainingStages}"
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Stage 2") {
            when {
                expression {
                    !skipRemainingStages
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    println "This text wont show up...."
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Stage 3") {
            when {
                expression {
                    !skipRemainingStages
                }
            }

            steps {
                script {
                    println "This text wont show up...."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is very simple example that sets `skipRemainingStages` to true at `Stage 1` and `Stage 2` and `Stage 3` get skipped because expression in the `when` block does not evaluates to true.

[image]

Alternatively you can call `error(String message)` step to stop the pipeline and set its status to `FAILED`. For example, if your stage 1 calls `error(msg)` step like:

```
stage("Stage 1") {
    steps {
        script {
            error "This pipeline stops here!"
        }
    }
}
```

In this case pipeline stops whenever `error(msg)` step is found and all remaining stages are ignored (`when` blocks are not even checked).

[image]

Of course you can call `error(msg)` depending on some condition to make it `FAILED` only if specific conditions are met.

Comment: What to test to know you have an error? Is there a `try catch` system? Because I don't want to test each line of my script.

Comment: thank you!! hard to find easy and complete examples

Answer (score 12):

You can use post in a stage to exit as follows:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('stage 1') {
            steps {
                 //step 1
            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
            steps {
                script{ 
                    //step 2
                }
            }
            post{
                success {
                }
                failure {
                    script{
                        sh "exit 1"
                        //or
                        error "Failed, exiting now..."
                    }
                }
                aborted {
                }
                unstable {
                    script{
                           sh "exit 1"
                          //or
                          error "Unstable, exiting now..."                    
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will abort the build and job wouldn't run further.

Answer (score 5):

You can also simply throw an Exception.  That will abort the build.
In fact simply setting the build status in a catch clause works pretty well.
You can also then add custom logic in the finally block for sending notifications for build status changes (email, Slack message etc)

So perhaps something like the following.   NOTE: I have copied some of this from an existing Jenkinsfile.   So not 100% sure this is the same syntax as you were using:

```
pipeline {
   try {
      stages {
         stage("stage1") {
             if (something) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong")
             }
         }

         stage("stage2") {

         }

      } 
  } catch (e) {
     currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
     throw e
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
stage('Set skipRemainingStages variable which decides, whether to run next stages or not') {
    steps {
        script {
            skipRemainingStages = true
            try {
                println("In if block")
                skipRemainingStages = true
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                println("Exception block: ${exc}")
                skipRemainingStages = false
            }

            if (skipRemainingStages) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                error("Stopping early!")
            }
        }
    }
}
stage('This will not execute if skipRemainingStages=true')
{.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mark the build as failed and then use `sh "exit 1"` to interrupt its execution in your Jenkins pipelines like below:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('stage 1') {
            steps {

            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
            steps {
                script{ 
                      if (something) {
                            currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                            sh "exit 1"
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```